# Medion P6685 Touchpad and Fn-key NOT recognized

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, touchpad, brightness

I have recently bought a Medion P6685 MD61222 (ML-210008 30025457) Laptop, next to Windows 10, I installed XUBUNTU 18.04.3 (LTS). As it turns out, the touchpad and Fn key are not functioning and are not recognized (i.e. "less /proc/bus/input/devices" does NOT show a touchpad, and "xev" command does not show any output when the Fn key is pressed or released - implying that the Fn-key combined with one the F-keys , like F10 for sound off, are not working). In Windows 10 all is working. I have updated the bios to its latest release without any luck.
I have installed and tried Ubuntu 18.04, Mint 19.2 and Xubuntu 19.04 all with the same results (touchpad and Fn key fails)

Any ideas and help to debug this problem further would be most welcome. Thanks in advance.

Additional information:
/proc/bus/input/devices

N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"  
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0   
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input0    
U: Uniq=    
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event0 leds   
B: PROP=0   
B: EV=120013    
B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe  
B: MSC=10   
B: LED=7    
    
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=045e Product=00cb Version=0111   
N: Name="Microsoft  Microsoft Basic Optical Mouse v2.0 "    
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input0   
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:045E:00CB.0002/input/input2 
U: Uniq=    
H: Handlers=mouse0 event2   
B: PROP=0   
B: EV=17    
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0    
B: REL=103  
B: MSC=10   
    
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=13d3 Product=56a0 Version=1601   
N: Name="USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD"   
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-10/button  
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.0/input/input3   
U: Uniq=    
H: Handlers=kbd event3  
B: PROP=0   
B: EV=3 
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0 
    
I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000   
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Mic" 
P: Phys=ALSA    
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input4    
U: Uniq=    
H: Handlers=event4  
B: PROP=0   
B: EV=21    
B: SW=10    
    
I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000   
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Headphone"   
P: Phys=ALSA    
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input5    
U: Uniq=    
H: Handlers=event5  
B: PROP=0   
B: EV=21    
B: SW=4 
    
I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000   
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3"   
P: Phys=ALSA    
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input6    
U: Uniq=    
H: Handlers=event6  
B: PROP=0   
B: EV=21    
B: SW=140   
    
I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000   
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7"   
P: Phys=ALSA    
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input7    
U: Uniq=    
H: Handlers=event7  
B: PROP=0   
B: EV=21    
B: SW=140   
    
I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000   
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8"   
P: Phys=ALSA    
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input8    
U: Uniq=    
H: Handlers=event8  
B: PROP=0   
B: EV=21    
B: SW=140   
    
I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000   
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9"   
P: Phys=ALSA    
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input9    
U: Uniq=    
H: Handlers=event9  
B: PROP=0   
B: EV=21    
B: SW=140   
    
I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000   
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10"  
P: Phys=ALSA    
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input10   
U: Uniq=    
H: Handlers=event10     
B: PROP=0   
B: EV=21    
B: SW=140   



Output of command: sudo lshw -C input
  *-usb:1
       description: Mouse
       product: Microsoft Basic Optical Mouse v2.0
       vendor: Microsoft
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@1:3
       version: 1.99
       capabilities: usb-1.10
       configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=2Mbit/s

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I recommend [edit]ing the content of `/proc/bus/input/devices` into your question as what is actually there is likely to be more useful in determining what is going on than the fact that what you expect to see isn't there. thank you for helping us help you! Also useful might be the output of `sudo lshw -C input`

Comment: In the meantime I tried other linux distros and of those Manjaro and MX Linux DON'T have the above described problem i.e. special Fn keys and Touchpad are working fine. As a consequence I have now switched over the MX linux which comes closest to Ubuntu  (especially with respect to installing a pacakges - using APT) .

Comment: I'm glad you found s solution that works for you! Did you by any chance check the differences between the output for MX, Manjaro and Xubuntu?

Comment: What I found out sofar is that in Xubuntu I needed to add ACPI=OFF in the Grub startup line for XUBUNTU otherwise it won't boot. In MX Linux and Manjory this setting is not required. If I do however Fn-keys and mousepad stop working in MX Linux also. So it must have something to do with ACPI handling in the various Linux disto's. There i are a lot of issues/solutions around ACPI I have seen sofar but on my laptop only ACPI=OFF works for XUBUNTU with the result that Fn-keys and mousepad fail!

Comment: You might find [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Reference/ACPITricksAndTips) useful...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop, and I had the same issue.
In my case, it was a failure related with acpi module (which manages this type of things). I had to disabled acpi on grub (acpi=off) because, otherwise, ubuntu doesn't boot due to a problem with thermal sensors.

Finally, I find out how to switch off just the thermal module on grub (etc/default/grub)

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash thermal.off=1"

instead of turning off the whole module

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"

So, check if acpi is running properly and if you have to disable something to run your OS just disable what is needed.

Hope it helps